# Show an UITableView in an UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller

I want to show an `UITableView` in a `UIAlertControler`. In [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVnUg.png) when I tap on the BarButtonItem(Play) bottom left, it must show an `UIAlertController` with the table view and than can choose the cell. How can I do that? I have search in Google but all I have found is in Objective-C.

I want an `UIAlertController` like this but in iOS 9. `UIAlertController` with StaticCell then the `UITableView` in the Section Header 1. Is that possible?

[image: UIAlertController]

Comment: see https://github.com/KyoheiG3/SimpleAlert

Comment: You cannot customize `UIAlertController`, but you can use a component that mimic it. CocoaControls/GitHub should have a component that looks like what you want.

Comment: in this example are Alert but not with a UITableview inside.